# which interfaces one class implements?

Tags: c#, asp.net

From code how can we know which interfaces one class implements?

Example:

```
interface IDrink
interface IEat

class Milk : IDrink    
class Water: IDrink    
class Potato: IEat
```

I want to know if Potato implements IDrink or not. How can I do it?

.

**Use of this:**

I've one method that receives one "`object myObject`" and I need to see if I cast it to IDrink or IEat.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can either cast it (which could throw an exception) or use the `as` operator.

```
private void DrinkIt(Object o) {
    IDrink possibleDrink = o as IDrink;

    if (possibleDrink == null)
        Console.WriteLine("Not a drink!");
    else {
        ChugItDown(possibleDrink);
        Console.WriteLine("That hit the spot!");
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter how many interfaces `o` implements - here you're just interested if it's an `IDrink`. If you want to get a complete list, you have to use reflection (`System.Reflection`):

```
Type [] interfaces = myObject.GetType().GetInterfaces();
```

Of course, `myObject` shouldn't be `null` - as a `null` has no type. You can then check if `interfaces` contains `IDrink`, `IEat` etc.

Answer (score 7):

Because no one mentioned it, you can use the `is` operator :

```
if (myObject is IEat)
   //It looks like food
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `as` operator:

```
void Method(Object myObject) {
  IDrink drink = myObject as IDrink;
  if (drink != null) {
    // Use the IDrink interface.
  }
}
```

If you just want to test for the interface and not use it you can use the `is` operator:

```
void Method(Object myObject) {
  if (myObject is IDrink) {
     // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: If `myObject` is null it has no type.

Comment: @Dryadwoods: Why are `as` and `is` not good with more than two interfaces?

Comment: Of course that "as" and "is" are good too, but when I commented that is not good, I said this in a way of the need to N if conditions to N different Interfaces.The solution of Vinay Sajip is better in the way I first test what I want first (priorities).

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a cheat this, but here's a couple of links which show you how to find out what interfaces an objects implements.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/600b6a24-8289-4ad6-a0a6-da354ab6923e/
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DoesATypeImplementAnInterface.aspx

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
typeof(IDrink).IsInstanceOf(myObject)
```

See MSDN for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isinstanceoftype.aspx

**UPDATE**

For example:

```
public interface IDrink{}
public interface IEat{}

public class Milk : IDrink{}
public class Water: IDrink  {}
public class Potato : IEat { }


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object milk = new Milk();
        Console.WriteLine("Is Milk an IDrink: {0}",
            typeof(IDrink).IsInstanceOfType(milk));
        Console.WriteLine("Is Milk an IEat: {0}",
            typeof(IEat).IsInstanceOfType(milk));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

produces the output:

> Is Milk an IDrink: True 
>   Is Milk an IEat: False

Comment: Sorry, after all you are right: bool isOrNot = typeof(IDrink).IsInstanceOfType(myObject);

Comment: The `is` operator is MUCH faster than using the `Type.IsInstanceOfType` method.